# Can you help to install "Not Installed" packages

Tags: package-management

[image: packages]

Hi there... I am really new on Linux system.
Can you help me to install "Not Installed" packages ???

Comment: You mean you want to install *everything*?

Comment: I though I downloaded packages but did not installed them. That's why, I asked help  to install them.  @Videonauth  said what satisfiy me.

Comment: @RuzimukhammadMamanazarov then you can accept my answer by chlicking the checkmark beside it. :) Wellcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You think now surely there are left out packages in your system, but that isn't true, your system is fully operational. This output means only there are more known packages you can install if you want. There is no need to install all and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to Ubuntu , I recommend you to [man](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/man) commands before you use them, `man` helps you to get the better understanding of commands and various options related with them . For example, if you want to know what does `apt-get` does , then you can simply type `man apt-get` and it will give you all the details required and related to that command.

Now since you believe that your system is missing some packages required for it  run smoothly, open terminal and type `apt-get install -f` and press Enter. This command will install unresolved dependencies i.e it will install all the packages that systems believe it needs in order to work smoothly. Read the output of `man apt-get` to know what else you can do with `apt-get` .